# What is the ellipsis badge on minimized terminal app in the dock mean?

Tags: terminal, dock, window-manager

[image]

I have another terminal window minimized next to it in the dock and it doesn't have the ellipsis. Also it doesn't have any running processes. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the question [Terminal doesn't show badge - how to enable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23191/terminal-doesnt-show-badge-how-to-enable). In the accepted answer it says:

> There is also an "unread text" indicator displayed in tabs, in the
>   form of ellipsis ("…"):
>
> This is displayed when anything is written to a background terminal, and, like the bell indicator, cleared when you activate that
>   terminal window/tab. An "unread text" ellipsis is also displayed on
>   minimized terminal windows in the Dock.